# gganimate showing transition along some objects

Tags: r, gganimate

I m trying to create animation to show transition along some nodes.  I want to show point moving from SRC to TGT  with transition change in intensity my df is like this below.

```
> df
  node intensity Lon Lat
1  SRC      0.90  40  60
2  TGT      0.89  80  40
3  TGT      0.80  40  30
4  TGT      0.99  30  20

library(ggplot2)
 library(gganimate)
 df <- read.table(text = "node intensity Lon Lat
                          SRC .9  40  60 
                            TGT .89 80   40
                            TGT  .8 40 30
                            TGT .99 30     20", header = TRUE)
 ggm <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size= intensity, colour=node)) +
      geom_point(alpha=.5)+
      transition_states(node)+
      labs(title = "test")+ 
      shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.5)
```

my desired output is to  show moving animation something like this

[image]

I am getting point stationary  SRC and TGT along frames

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired effect by making three copies of the source and assigning a group to each point that should go from its source to target location.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gganimate/vignettes/gganimate.html

> The key is the group aesthetic. You may be familiar with this
>   aesthetic from plotting lines and polygons, but in gganimate it takes
>   a more central place. Data that have the same group aesthetic are
>   interpreted as being linked across states. The semantics of the group
>   aesthetic in ggplot2 is such that if it is undefined it will get
>   calculated based on the interaction of all discrete aesthetics (sans
>   label). If none exists, such as in our iris animation, all data will
>   get the same group, and will thus be matched by gganimate.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
df <- read.table(text = "node intensity Lon Lat grp
                          SRC .9  40  60 1
                          SRC .9  40  60 2
                          SRC .9  40  60 3
                            TGT .89 80   40 1
                            TGT  .8 40 30 2
                            TGT .99 30     20 3", header = TRUE)
ggm <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, size= intensity, colour=node, group = grp)) +
  geom_point(alpha=.5)+
  transition_states(node)+
  labs(title = "test")+ 
  shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Jon. How can I add more SRC and TGT to this above df to show a second node animation in time for ex: SRC2 and TGT2?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Should those transition at the same time, or a different time?

Comment: Not at same time but one after the other in time.

Comment: Perhaps this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671755/gganimate-animate-multiple-paths-based-on-time/52671884#52671884